# Pandas: Comparing consecutive Rows from different Colum

Tags: pandas, indexing, rows, python-2.x

Hi im having trouble comparing two consecutive rows form diffrent colums, both columns have boolean values. I need to create a new column called "lasthit" with boolean values, that evaluate if the ith row of the column "Response" is equal to the ith+1 row of the column "Confidence". For that i have the following code:

This is mi data frame (it actually is a [2539 rows x 19 columns] matrix):

```
      circle_rt    response   circle_number confidence confidence_rt  nose  \
0     12.746130     True              0       True      26.686977  0.000000   
1      5.497027     True              6       True       2.219596  0.120000   
2      3.789324     True              2       True       4.992639  0.118931   
3      7.716839     True              2       True       3.139458  0.067106   
4      4.219006     True              7       True       2.680553  0.000000   
5      6.635735     True              1       True       1.643296  0.015449   
6     12.768281    False              2       True       2.045460  0.000000   
7      4.293818     True              0       True       1.915654  0.060843   
8      2.280957     True              5       True       2.384980  0.000000
```

For example when comparing the value of truth of the 6th row in "response" vs the 7th row in "confidence", the value of the "lashit" should be TRUE, becouse they are not equal.

```
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))
for i in range (0,len(df)):
    for j in range (1,len(df.loc[0])):
        df['hitlast']=(df.response.loc[j-1] == df.confidence.loc[j])
        #sumhitlast=+df.response.loc[j-1] == df.confidence.loc[j]

df.head()
print(df)
```

when i do this i get the following

```
                       filename                           subject       hitlast
0      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
1      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
2      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
3      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
4      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
5      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
6      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
7      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
8      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
9      datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
10     datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
11     datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
12     datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
13     datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True   
14     datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out   datos\1479123701 - 1.meta.out    True
```

The Problem is that all of the values in "hitlast" are TRUE, and there should be 1 FALSE as a result of comparing the value of truth of the 6th row in "response" vs the 7th row in "confidence"!

I dont get whats wrong here, im no sure if its an indexation problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you need `shift`:

```
df['response'] & df['confidence'].shift(1).fillna(True)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
8     True
dtype: bool
```